# Positive polynomials in $\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: polynomials

Let $P\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ be a polynomial such that $P (x)\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 0$.
Show that there exists two polynomials $A, B\in \mathbb{R}[X]$  so that $$P=A^{2}+X\cdot B^{2}$$

Comment: Please always show the own thoughts. For instance try to say something in the special case of $P=x^4+x^2+1$. Else there are good chances for other downvotes. (Not mine, i type first...) It is always a good idea to mention the source, the level of the problem, the own level, one, two, or more trials... Please also use mathjax, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: Write $$P(x) = Q(x)+xR(x)$$

where $Q(x) ={1\over 2}(P(x)+P(-x))$ and $R(x) = {P(x)-Q(x)\over x}$ and try to prove that $Q$ and $R$ are perfect square of a real polynomials.

---

**This is better:**

**1. step:** Suppose all the zeroes of $P$ are real and simple (i.e. first degree). Then $$P(x) = a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)$$ Because $P(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$ they all have to be nonpositive. So $y_i = -x_i$ is positive for each $i$. So we have $$P(x) = a(x+y_1)(x+y_2)...(x+y_n)$$

Now we can prove that such polynomial is of a form we want:

Say $a>0$ and if $M = A^2+xB^2$ then $$(x+a)M = x(A+aB)^2+(aA-xB)^2$$ and we are done.

---

**2. step** Now if $P$ has also nosimple real zeroes, then we can write it as $$P= Q\cdot R^2$$
where $Q$ again has only simple real zeros, so we can use 1. step and we are done.

---

**3. step** Say $P$ has also nonreal zeros. So $P=Q\cdot R$ where $Q$ has only real zeros and $R$ only nonreal (so they are in conjugate pairs). Now we can use step 2. for $Q$ and we can prove that we can write $R$ as $C^2+D^2$. I leave that to you. Only thing is to prove now that product of polynomial $A^2 +xB^2$ and $C^2+D^2$ is again of form $A_1^2+xB_1^2$ and that I also leave to you.

Comment: Thanks Greedoid, but can you elaborate more?